# SQL Server how to get last inserted data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I ran a large query (~30mb) which inserts data in ~20 tables. Accidentally, I selected wrong database. There are only 2 tables with same name but with different columns. Now I want to make sure that no data is inserted in this database, I just don't know how.

Comment: use permissions to prevent accidentally inserting in wrong DB

Comment: This is why all databases should have audit tables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has a timestamp you can test for that.

Also sql-server keeps a log of all transactions.

See: https://web.archive.org/web/20080215075500/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-recover-data-from-sql-server-s-log-files.html

This will show you how to examine the log to see if any inserts happened.

Answer (score 0):

**Best option go for Trigger**

> Use trigger to find the db name and
>   table name and all the history of
>   records manipulated